# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Post Issue

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and learning it for website monitoring automation. For learning purposes, I am trying to log on to the below site, but its not going through.

I have reviewed some post and videos on YouTube for same, but I don't understand where my mistake is.

Any help on this would be greatful.

Thank you,

Code:

```
   $abv = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://care.ideacellular.com/wps/portal/account/account-login" -sessionvariable svb
$abv
$svb
$loginform=$abv.Forms[2]
$loginform.Fields["ns_Z7_JH56H4K0K0NI90AS8HP1UF00I1_mobileNumber"]="mobilenumber"
$loginform.Fields["ns_Z7_JH56H4K0K0NI90AS8HP1UF00I1_password"]="password"
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ( "https://care.ideacellular.com/wps/portal/account/account-login" ) -WebSession $svb -Method Post -Body $loginform.Fields
```

Comment: Are there no error messages? What does "not going through" mean?

Comment: Apology for delayed response. I meant , after last statement of the code I should be see the content of Home page , however I can see only log in page content so I understood it is not taking me to home page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your are new on Powershell, but it looks like you are also new on Web Monitoring, here are two stating places.

You should have a look at :

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) using it natively or with [Selenium PowerShell eXtensions](https://sepsx.codeplex.com/).

[html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for example : [HTML Agility Pack Rocks Your Screen Scraping World](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/).

Comment: Yes, I am new to web monitoring also. I looking at pointers given by you. Thank you.